# Large .zip files download incomplete

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, zip

I am a severe novice, but I did quite a lot of research before posting, so I hope you can help.

I'm trying to serve a large .zip file that is hosted on an Apache server, about 6.4 Gb.  The file shows complete download in browser, but in fact only about 500Mb have been downloaded.  This seems like a very common problem and have found a lot of other posts and information on the web, but the problem has been persistent for me.

[Large Zip file offered for download using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734059/large-zip-file-offered-for-download-using-php)

[IE download incomplete even though it claims success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993056/ie-download-incomplete-even-though-it-claims-success)

[Large zip downloads failing only in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979105/large-zip-downloads-failing-only-in-ie)

I have been testing with Chrome 39.0.2171.71, but I get the same problem with FireFox and IE.  I think my file is much larger than what others have been posting about, therefore perhaps their solutions helped the situation, but didn't fix the root problem.  I have a second .zip file that is about 400Mb, and I use the same http headers with success.

The most useful article I have found is this: http://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/ and I have copied much of the php shown below from that source, as it appears other posters on this website have done.

I have also tried using X-SendFile, but I don't think my webhost has the appropriate Apache module installed.  I've spent all day working on this, and have run out of ideas!  I have used a download manager with success, I don't know if this was just by chance or what, but I don't want to require my clients to have to download and install a separate program just to get the .zip file.

```
<?php 
// HTTP Headers for ZIP File Downloads

// set example variables
$filename = "huge.zip";
$filepath = "****";

// http headers for zip downloads
// header("X-Sendfile: $filepath$filename");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
set_time_limit(0);
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
?>
```

Here are the response headers when I run the php above

```
Remote Address:76.162.142.242
Request URL:****/GetSW.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic ******
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1176828605.1417985823
DNT:1
Host:www.teamursa.org
Referer:http://www.teamursa.org/****.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36

Response Headers

Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="huge.zip"
Content-Length:6720560824
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Sun, 07 Dec 2014 22:16:57 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=120
Pragma:public
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17
```

Comment: Foremost you shouldn't let PHP handle the file sending. Instead of `readfile()` delegate the actual transfer to Apache, which indeed is where `mod_xsendfile` should be used. Your PHP script doesn't implement partial / byte-range transfers and thus resumed HTTP downloads. And it's very very much not worth the effort to reimplement any of that in PHP. -- So what's the original reason for that PHP script wrapper?

Comment: ftp is more large file transfer *friendly* than http, if you have that option

Comment: my best guess is that your php script just gets killed because of `max_execution_time` setting http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time. So your browser gets just what readfile manages to send in that time window.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  I have added and removed the max_execution_time setting, with no effect. FTP works great, but I don't want people to have to download and install an FTP client.  @mario I could try and see if my webhost can install mod_xsendfile for me, I'm not sure what is involved with that or if they would do it.  I don't know what else to do beside the php wrappers, I guess.  Previously I just had a link to the huge.zip file in my html, but php seemed like a more efficient way of specifying http headers than with the .htaccess file.

Comment: If it's just about additional headers, use [`mod_cern_meta`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cern_meta.html) and a separate `huge.zip.meta` file which lists the raw HTTP headers to prepend. Alternatively a `RewriteRule huge.zip - [T=archive/zip]` or a plain [`Header add "Content-Disposition: attachment"`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) for the whole folder.

Comment: Ok, great!  I'll work on that!  Overall though, the strategy of getting such a large .zip file to transfer with http would be unchanged? and I'm worried I'll end up with the same results as my bit of php.  I'm new enough at this that it will take me a bit to implement what you suggested and see if it helps.  Separate note: When I changed the Content-type: application/octet-stream to application/.zip and don't specify binary Content-Transfer-Encoding the huge.zip file usually gets to about 2-4 Gb of the 6.7  Gb before the browser declares it "complete".  I don't know if this is a hint at all.

Comment: most (all) browsers do ftp now

Comment: @Dagon Thank You!!  I figured out how to just make an FTP link on my site instead of an http link.  I didn't know you could do that without a client like FileZilla, just shows how green I am.  Are there any downsides to this?  One thing I'll have research is if it's possible to protect certain  files just like you can do with a .htaccess and .htpassword files.  At the moment the ftp links either require the ftp credentials to be entered in a dialog, or I have to write the credentials into the link (in which case they're available to anyone who examines the link).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to increase the memory limit on the server. Try the below just after the opening PHP tag

`ini_set('memory_limit','16M');`

And just keep increasing from 16M

Comment: [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) does not buffer the whole file or even larger parts of. It's specifically designed to pipe from a file handle directly to the CGI/STDOUT stream.

Comment: @mario Ah. I see that readfile doesn't cause any memory issues. My bad. I overlooked that

Comment: I have read that output buffering can be a problem, I believe that I am not using it in the code I have pasted above, correct?  I'm trying to find the post that made me think output buffering was not appropriate in my situation, but can't place it at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you try using a web browser to download file directly, meaning you go to the address that file is stored at. E.g www.example.com/downloads/download.zip Hope this helps